# NextJs environment variables are not available on developement and production server

Tags: azure, next.js, environment-variables, next.js13

I know that this has been asked before, but none of the answers solved my problem.

I am trying to setup authentication for a website using redux , I have a localServer which i develope and test before pushing to production,azure web services was used to deploy
on Localhost:3000 and a production

On production the environment variables are added but the baseurl is replaced by the base url of the production i.e https://api.example.com is replaced by example.com which is the baseurl for the production server

This is how i have added the environment variables to my .env.local file ,

```
API_CLIENT_SECRET='secret here'
CLIENT_TYPE=confidential
API_CLIENT_ID='id here'
API_BASE_URL='https:api.example.com'
```

and this is how i am the client_secret and client id in my #authslice.js

```
import { apiSlice } from "../services/apiSlice";

const clientId = process.env.API_CLIENT_ID;
const clientSecret = process.env.API_CLIENT_SECRET;
const authApiSlice = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    retrieveUser: builder.query({
      query: () => "auth/userinfo/",
    }),
```

And this is how i am calling the baseurl in a file called apislice.js

```
const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({
  baseUrl: `${process.env.API_BASE_URL}/`,
  credentials: "include",
});
```

I tried calling them in my next.config.js as below but they are not available on production

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
  },
  env: {
    API_BASE_URL: process.env.API_BASE_URL,
    API_CLIENT_ID: process.env.API_CLIENT_ID,
    API_CLIENT_SECRET: process.env.API_CLIENT_SECRET,
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```